# Как получить код ответа сервера 429 через ymaps.geocode()

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api, geocode

При достижении лимита запросов к API сервер должен возвращать ошибку 429 вида `GeocoderQuotaExceeded: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests`

Из какого параметра получить код ответа (будь то 200 или 429) в методе:

```js
ymaps.geocode(coords).then(function(res) {}, function(err) {});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У метода ymaps.geocode() есть ограничение на кол-во запросов. Признаком является получение HTTP-статуса 429. Не могу понять как получить содержимое заголовка из промиса в этом методе. Если бы использовал $.ajax или fetch, то там есть специальные поля для этого. А в этом методе - не понятно.